# How to send SMS on the Skype for Linux 8.10.0.4?

Tags: skype

Well, from today, I discovered that I cannot use the old skype-4.3.0.37, where the SMS sending actually worked (that was apparently announced on [End of Life of Skype for Linux 4.3](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/end-of-life-of-skype-for-linux-43/70fe7036-ddf3-4fa3-9c06-1bca3ec0226c)); the Skype docs still refer to this old version:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12044/how-do-i-send-sms-text-messages-from-skype-for-linux

[image]

Now Skype is only 64-bit, and has a deb repo: https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux/

... and it is now some Electron/Chromium application, and of course, there's no SMS - what I was otherwise paying for - anywhere:

[image: Screenshot-Skype.png]

On the left you don't have a contact list anymore, but "conversation" list, and if I do raise the contact list and right-click a contact, there's no "Send SMS" anywhere; on the chat box there's only "Open Moji picker" and "Add media or files", again no "Send SMS".

(Btw, they've done the same on Skype for Android - no SMS there either)

So, I thought, maybe I can use Skype for Web, but:

[image]

... "we're a bit overloaded".

So, how can I send SMS now?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on topic, and not a rant about Microsoft and their product, for which this site is not a support forum. Software and service recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: @dobey - I edited it, hopefully its better now.

Comment: "If the question starts with 'why', the answer is most likely 'money.'"  Slight paraphrase of a quote from SF author Robert A. Heinlein.

Comment: The "question" is still too ranty and off topic.

Comment: Thanks @dobey - edited again, is it better now?

Comment: Not really. It is still a question for Skype support, and not really Ubuntu. At least you've gotten rid of the rude/rant bits, but IMO it's still off topic. It really needs an official answer from MS/Skype on where the development is headed, and what will become of the feature.

Comment: Good question, but you may want to obscure some of the personal information in the first screenshot.  This fits better on superuser though, it's not Ubuntu specific.

Comment: @gerrit I can't really think of anything that is "Ubuntu specific". [Our scope isn't limited to things that only run on Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14535/85695). And a good thing too, we'd have an empty site, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the answer is - if you want to send SMS, do NOT use Skype for Linux (or Android); if you're lucky enough to get on Skype for Web, there is a possibility there:

[image]

There is the little "Via Skype" button there, if you click it, you have the option of "Send SMS".

Comment: I've just had a look at my "upgraded" Skype / Ubuntu application, or Web Application thing. You're right, no sms.
However...... if you log into Outlook [which you'll have access to as you have a Skype account [outlook.com]] you can access Skype there, and there IS a "send sms", just as there is in the image above from SDAAU.
Hope this helps.